# mirror bits in char, limited operators +,<<,& no loops allowed, C language

Tags: char, bitwise-operators, bit, mirror

Preparing for exam and got stuck at this question:
Allowed operators are `<<,+,&` **no loops** allowed and **minimum temp variables**. 
Write a function in C, that gets 4-bit number (char) and returns mirrored (relative to center) bits.
Example: given `b4,b3,b2,b1` return `b1,b2,b3,b4`

O_o thanks!

it might be not clear, but general language tools are allowed ('==',if,>,< etc..)

Comment: On pretty much any system today, a char is 8 bits, not 4 bits.

Comment: it's not for today's systems, it's for tomorrow's exam ;]

Comment: Where did you get stuck? If your exam will be full of this stuff, the code at http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#BitReverseObvious is a _fantastic_ place to learn from.

Comment: i'm stuck at how to move b4 and b3.. thanks for  the link!

Comment: You shouldn't actually move the bits - you should create a new char that has the same bits as the original, but in reversed order.

Comment: yes! i don't care it's a new variable....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible given the constraints of only the operators `<<, +, &` and no other constructs besides return.

To move b3 from the 3rd position to the 2nd position, you will need a way to shift to the right which requires something like >> or /.  Of the operators provided, none can be used with b3 to set the 2nd or 1st bit position.

if you can use if statements and the assignment operator `=`, it is possible.  You can then write a messy solution such as

```
char flip(char c)
{
  char f;
  f = (c & 1) << 3 + (c & 2) << 1;
  if (c & 4)
    f = f + 2;
  if (c & 8)
    f = f + 1;
  return f;
}
```

A more ugly but shorter one liner if you can use the similar to `if` `?` operator.

```
char flip(char c)
{
  return (c & 1) << 3 + (c & 2) << 1 + ((c & 4) ? 2 : 0) + ((c & 8) ? 1 : 0);
}
```